# Not able to set overflow: hidden; on a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am not able to set overflow: hidden; on div wrapper for this script.

Please look at this js fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/CwzAD/1/

My aim is to display 10 cells (200 px in height) on the page and showing only animation within this limit, so to act as a mask.

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Any alternative approach even using JavaScript if with only CSS is not possible?

```
    *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #pageset {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 500px;
        height: 200px;
        border: 1px solid rgba(0,255,255,1);
        -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    }
    #wrapper {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 500px;
        background-color: green;
        /*overflow: scroll;*/ /* PROBLEM HERE----------------*/
        /*height: 200px;*/ /* PROBLEM HERE----------------*/
    }
    #navigator {
        position: absolute;
        left: 600px;
    }
    ul {
        list-style: none;
        /* margin:0px;
        padding:0px;*/
    }
    li:nth-child(even) {
        background: #d80000;
    }
    li {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
        float: left;
        margin: 0px;
    }
    .focus {
        background-color: yellow !important;
    }
    .btn {
        float: left;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        border: 2px gray solid;
        margin: 10px;
        background-color: #f0f0f0 ;
    }
    .icon {
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        border: 2px gray solid;
        margin: 10px;
        background-color: #99ff66;        
    }
```

Solution here
http://jsfiddle.net/Uz5a9/

Comment: Are you askink about the fact it only shows 8 items instead of 10 or did I misunderstood the question?

Comment: script show 10 rows, every row as 5 cells. I need to show the animation within within a MASK with the size of 2 rows, so 200px. Maybe it was not clear in my question :-)

Comment: hm, I don't see anything wrong with it o_o I actually see 10 in the example sent.

Comment: try to click the DIV DOWN so you can see the script in action

Comment: please add a comment when you downvote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, what you need to do is use the `#wrapper` div as a container, which is only 200px high.
The `.content` div you generate should then scroll inside that wrapper.

To accomplish this you need to position the wrapper relatively, and then position the content div absolutely inside the wrapper. The wrapper should never move around.

The content can be as high as you want, the wrapper should always stay 200px high.

Check the following fiddle, which demonstrates exactly this: http://jsfiddle.net/Uz5a9/

Comment: Why the downvote? This actually does exactly what the topic poster wants.

Comment: why this down vote?.... thanks Gerrit your script just works fine and solve my problem. Many many thanks for your help on this :-).

Answer (score 1):

Try this css it will work fine **[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/lvtrvd/hAPvv/)**

```
.content {
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden
}
```

Comment: I am sorry but this solutions does not mask the first two rows

Comment: I don't know in which browser, but in chrome I still see all the other squares. - This doesn't work anyhow, since it hides the previous squares.

Answer (score 0):

Just apply these additional rules to `#wrapper`:

```
#wrapper { max-height: 200px; overflow: hidden; }
```

and it seems to work just as described.

Comment: Please try to click on div DOWN, you will see an animation. Using your solution I am afraid I cannot see the other cells, they should slide up